# Displaying local storage data in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I currently have this stored in my localStorage:

```
{cart: "[{"Author":"Micheal Grant","title":"Gone"},{{"Author":"Micheal 
Grant","title":"Fear"}]"
```

I was just wondering how I would go about retrieving this data and displaying it in a table:

For example:

```
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> Book Title </th>
      <th> Author </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Book_Title">Gone </td>
      <td class="Author">Micheal Grant</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Book_Title">The Knife of never letting go</td>
      <td class="Author">Ryan Howard</td>

    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `I was just wondering` If you want debugging help, post what you've tried so far - SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Have you tried using `localStorage.getItem()`?

Comment: `JSON.parse()` https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp But it only works if your JSON string is properly formatted. `{"cart": [{"Author":"Micheal Grant","title":"Gone"},{"Author":"Micheal Grant","title":"Fear"}]}` https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you retrieve item from localStorage like `localStorage.getItem(dataObj);`, you can use jQuery's `each()` to loop through all the items. Inside the handler function to create the `tr` with the values and append that to `tbody`.

Please notice the use of [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) inside `append()`.

Try the following way:

```js
//localStorage.getItem(dataObj);
var jsonData = {cart: [{"Author":"Micheal Grant","title":"Gone"},{"Author":"Micheal Grant","title":"Fear"}]};

$.each(jsonData.cart, function(key, value){
  $('tbody').append(`<tr>
  <td class="Book_Title">${value.title}</td>
  <td class="Author">${value.Author}</td>
</tr>`);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> Book Title </th>
      <th> Author </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is what you should do

```
var cart= JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('cart' ) );
    $.each(cart, function(key, value){
      $('tbody').append(`<tr>
      <td class="Book_Title">${cart.title}</td>
      <td class="Author">${cart.Author}</td>
    </tr>`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the data from `localStorage` using `localStorage.getItem` function.

Once you have the data, iterate through the `cart` attribute, and use `javascript template strings` to create the `html` structure. Advantage of using template strings is that it's more readable and you can easily insert javascript variables inside them using `${}`.

```js
//localStorage.getItem(dataObj);
var data = {
  cart: [{
    "Author": "Micheal Grant",
    "title": "Gone"
  }, {
    "Author": "Micheal Grant",
    "title": "Fear"
  }]
};

var tableData = data.cart.map(book => (
  `
    <tr>
      <td>${book.title}</td>
      <td>${book.Author}</td>
    </tr>
  `
)).join('');

var tbody = document.querySelector('#body');
tbody.innerHTML = tableData;
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Book Title </th>
      <th> Author </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="body">
  </tbody>
</table>
```